# Use a Dynamic pattern in grep from a file

Tags: regex, awk, grep

So here is the issue. I have a file say A.java. Now don't bother about syntax. But here is what I aim to achieve.

```
import com.random.OrderSRO;
import com.random.SuborderSRO;

    public A {


        public void doRandom(){
            OrderSRO orderSRO = service.getOrderByCode(request).getOrderSRO();
            oEDTO.setCustomerName(orderSRO.getCustomerName());
            for (SuborderSRO suborderSRO : orderSRO.getSuborders()) {
                SOI undeliveredSOI = iShService.getSOIBySuborder(suborderSRO.getCode());
            oEDTO.setSuborders(allSuborders);
            oEDTO.setShDetail(pack.getShDetail());
            oEDTO.setShMethod(pack.getShMethod().getCode());
            oEDTO.setPurchaseDate(DateUtils.dateToString(orderSRO.getCreated(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            oEDTO.setTotalAmount(orderSRO.getSellingPrice());
            oEDTO.setPaidAmount(orderSRO.getPaidAmount());
            oEDTO.setSdCash(orderSRO.getSdCash());
            oEDTO.setShDetailsRequired(true);
        }
        public void doRandom1() {
            OrderSRO orderSRO1 = service.getOrderByCode(request).getOrderSRO();              
            oEDTO.setPurchaseDate(DateUtils.dateToString(orderSRO1.getCreated(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            oEDTO.setTotalAmount(orderSRO1.getSellingPrice());
            oEDTO.setPaidAmount(orderSRO1.getPaidAmount());
            oEDTO.setSdCash(orderSRO1.getSdCash());
        }
    }
```

I need to check what methods of OrderSRO are being used in A.java. Let me explain the method that I use.

So I need to check for patterns like

```
OrderSRO orderSRO = orderClientService.getOrderByCode(request).getOrderSRO();
```

Now I have variable orderSRO available. I need to now again grep ***this variable in the same file A.java***

Although I have been able to achieve it but my method is not clean. Wondering if it can be done smartly, say in one line

```
grep -o 'OrderSRO .*=' EmailServiceImpl.java | awk '{ct[$2];} END {for (var in ct) {str=str "|" var "\\.[a-zA-Z]*"};print str}' >> pat2.txt

cat pat2.txt. This gives me 
orderSRO1\.[a-zA-Z]*|orderSRO\.[a-zA-Z]*

grep -Ewof pat2.txt A.java | sort -u

orderSRO.getCode
orderSRO.getCreated
orderSRO.getCustomerName
orderSRO.getMobile
orderSRO.getPaidAmount
orderSRO.getSdCash
orderSRO.getSellingPrice
orderSRO.getSuborders
orderSRO1.getMobile
orderSRO1.getPaidAmount
orderSRO1.getSdCash
orderSRO1.getSellingPrice
orderSRO1.getSuborders
```

Comment: Don't use grep for this. Use something that understands java. Like an IDE, static analyzer, or similar toolset.

Comment: I have no. of files, most of them I would access thru a UI based tool. I have a way to download them, however yes your method is also another way. Only advantage with grep is, it will give me exactly what fields are being used. The OrderSRO that I mention, in my case has around 50 fields which I means I will have to do 50 searches, carefully note down each file, hence my gravitation towards grep.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help myself.  Here's an extremely custom awk script:

```
awk -F"[.]*OrderSRO[ ]*|[ ]*=" 'NF>2 {a[$2]; next} {for( i in a ) {c=split($0, line, i".|[(][)]"); if(c==3&&line[2]!~/^\./) print i"."line[2]}}' A.java
```

which yields:

```
orderSRO.getCustomerName
orderSRO.getSuborders
orderSRO.getCode
orderSRO.getCreated
orderSRO.getSellingPrice
orderSRO.getPaidAmount
orderSRO.getSdCash
orderSRO1.getCreated
orderSRO1.getSellingPrice
orderSRO1.getPaidAmount
orderSRO1.getSdCash
```

where method calls are in file order and has at least the following assumptions:

- Variable declarations are one to a line
- The method calls are for POJO getters w/o args
- Said getter calls are one to a line

It doesn't match the question output because things like `orderSRO.getMobile()` don't exist in the sample `A.java`.

Here's a multi-line view:

```
awk -F"[.]*OrderSRO[ ]*|[ ]*=" '
NF>2 {a[$2]; next}
{
  for( i in a ) {
    c=split($0, line, i".|[(][)]")
    if(c==3&&line[2]!~/^\./)
      print i"."line[2]
  }
}' A.java
```

which can be translated like:

- Set `FS` to find the variable name when `NF>2`
- when `NF>2`, add the variable name to an array, don't attempt to process the line
- For every line that's not a variable name, process it
- `split()` the line on variable name + "." or "()" ( which is why this only works for no arg getters )
- When the `split()` count (`c`) is 3, the 2nd element should be the getter
- except when "()" leads to a false positive, so throw out methods that start with "."
- print out the variable name followed by a "." and the no arg getter method name.

If you have to do this all the time, you're better off using something that understands code natively.  That said, I can't think of a way to do this in Eclipse w/o multiple searches.